# Cannot read property 'hasRole' of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I tried to listen to a dm but you mustn`t have a selected role.

```
if (!message.member.hasRole('447778989914718218')) {
  if (message.channel.type == "dm") {
    if (message.content == "1") {

      client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).removeRole('447778997766586380')
      client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).removeRole('478930168875057152')
      client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).addRole('447778989914718218')
      //message.delete();

    } else if (message.content == "2") {

      //var server = client.guilds.get("447726259246727168");
      //server.channels.find(channels => channels.name === "bot-test").send(`nice `)
      client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).removeRole('447778989914718218')
      client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).removeRole('478930168875057152')
      client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).addRole('447778997766586380')
      message.channel.delete();

    } else if (message.content == "3") {

      client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).removeRole('447778989914718218')
      client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).removeRole('447778997766586380')
      client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).addRole('478930168875057152')

    }
  }
}
```

But than there is an error:

```
(node:15292) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasRole' of null
 (C:\Users\Megaport\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\handlers\MessageCreate.js:9:34)
    at WebSocketPacketManager.handle (C:\Users\Megaport\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\packets\WebSocketPacketManager.js:103:65)
    at WebSocketConnection.onPacket (C:\Users\Megaport\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:333:35)
    at WebSocketConnection.onMessage (C:\Users\Megaport\Desktop\bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketConnection.js:296:17)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\Megaport\Desktop\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Receiver._receiver.onmessage (C:\Users\Megaport\Desktop\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:137:47)
    at Receiver.dataMessage (C:\Users\Megaport\Desktop\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:409:14)
    at Receiver.getData (C:\Users\Megaport\Desktop\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:347:12)
    at Receiver.startLoop (C:\Users\Megaport\Desktop\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:143:16)
    at Receiver.add (C:\Users\Megaport\Desktop\bot\node_modules\ws\lib\receiver.js:117:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:597:20)
(node:15292) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15292) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: @Andreas Thanks, deleted my comment.

Comment: The problem is that the message has no `member` property. I never used discord.js but according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/1165) this happens if the message is received in DM/GroupDM text channels or for webhook messages.

Answer (score 1):

message.member can be null when

- no Guild present ( Message sent in DM )
- GuildMember not chached ( common issue when your bot is used by lots of people ) you can fix that by using Guild#fetchMember ( or Guild.members#fetch on master ) this will return the member Object when you resolve the promise
- the message was sent per webhook

Answer (score 0):

Normally `.hasRole` doesn't exist if you haven't defined it anywhere.

Try to use the following code:

```
if (!message.member.roles.has('447778989914718218')) {    
    if (message.channel.type == "dm") {

        if (message.content == "1") {


            client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).removeRole('447778997766586380')
            client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).removeRole('478930168875057152')
            client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).addRole('447778989914718218')
            //message.delete();
        } else
        if (message.content == "2") {

            //var server = client.guilds.get("447726259246727168");
            //server.channels.find(channels => channels.name === "bot-test").send(`nice `)
            client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).removeRole('447778989914718218')
            client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).removeRole('478930168875057152')
            client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).addRole('447778997766586380')
            message.channel.delete();
        } else  
        if (message.content == "3") {
            client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).removeRole('447778989914718218')
            client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).removeRole('447778997766586380')

            client.guilds.get('447726259246727168').members.get(message.author.id).addRole('478930168875057152')

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I cant.There is an error: Cannot read property 'roles' of null

Comment: The problem is not that `hasRole` doesn't exist but that `member` doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you tell us how you defined message?

Comment: client.on('message', async message => {here is my code })

Comment: Ohh yes. You have to check if the type of the channel is a guild text channel and not a dm because if it's a dm you don't receive guildMember